# Program for drawing eye-catching graphs for presentations?

Tags: graphs, presentation

I am looking for programs to draw charts/curves, as we can do it in Excel or Powerpoint. My requirements are:

- Main focus is on graphics rather than data. It can be a symbolic
  curve without real data. It is useful to draw the curve with a
  freehand tool, then normalized by the software.
- It must be eye-catching graphs, well-designed and colorful wish
  shines and shades.
- Easy to use with ready options. I need to draw lots of graphs
  quickly.
- can be Windows or Mac (or even Linux), in order of preference
- price is not important if it is in a reasonable range

This is for a business, not personal.